# Using numeric file content as int (Haskell)

Tags: database, haskell, types, io, int

Is there some way I can use the contents of a file, which contain a counter value ( increment id for a database system ) as a regular int?

We're trying to create a little database system in Haskell, and need to keep track of the increment ids of tables. We figured the only "easy" way to do this is by saving them in a plain txt file. However, when retrieving them, the return type will be `IO Int`. Our database table definition requires an `Int` for the id though.

Does anyone have an idea how to use the increment id ( or integer value in general ) from a txt file for a class instance that requires an `Int` value?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: An example of code illustrating the problem:

```
data SomeTable = SomeTable { id :: Int, testField :: String }
someRow = SomeTable (generateNextId "SomeTable") "Test"
```

Where `generateNextId` reads the current increment id from a file ( and therefore has type `IO Int` and not `Int` ).

Comment: .Reading from a file is inherently an I/O operation - so you will need an `IO` in the return type. Therefore either you will need the `id` field to have type `IO Int` or (probably better) `someRow` needs to have type `IO SomeTable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well `IO Int` is an action, like reading a keystroke, that results in an `Int`.  So execute the action to obtain an Int:

```
data SomeTable = SomeTable { id :: Int, testField :: String }
someRow :: IO SomeTable
someRow =
    do i <- generateNextId "SomeTable"
       return (SomeTable i "Test")

someRowAlternative :: IO SomeTable
someRowAlternative =
    SomeTable <$> generateNextId "SomeTable" <*> pure "Test"
```